# "The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted" while configuring Primary Domain Controller

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, domain

I want to configure the Primary Domain Controller (PDC). But, when I input user name and password in the domain, a dialog is shown:

> The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted

I use Ubuntu 10.04 as a server and Windows 7 Ultimate as a client.